# FlutterPusher not connecting to host in release version

Tags: android, laravel, flutter, websocket, pusher

I am developing a flutter app which use [flutter_pusher_client](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pusher_client) with [laravel_echo](https://pub.dev/packages/laravel_echo). The websocket server is developed using [Laravel WebSockets](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets) . Also added internet permission to `AndroidManifest.xml` and REST API requests works fine. The issue is `FlutterPusher` does not connect to websocket server in release build but connects and works fine in debug build.

Comment: Do you encounter any errors? Please share if so.

Comment: @doydoy No errors showing. Code is exactly same as example provided here. https://pub.dev/packages/laravel_echo#-example-tab-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. Flutter build release use Google's R8 code shrinker by default and It removes `flutter_pusher_client` codes while shrinking. So if you are using Google R8 code shrinker please add following rule to `proguard-rules.pro` file.

```
-keep class com.github.heywhy.flutter_pusher.** { *; }
```